# PHP Unlink Not working

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to delete photo in php using unlink. I have used it earlier on other server but this time it is not working. I have used absolute path for a test but still does not works:

I have used it as:
    unlink('img1.jpg');

and :

```
unlink('http://www.mysite.com/img1.jpg');
```

Please anyone having such experience?

Comment: You cannot delete using an url. Did you try a full filesystem path, like `/var/www/mysite.com/img1.jpg`?

Comment: Is there any error? Maybe you don't have permissions to delete this file or the file is somewhere else on the server. `unlink` with http://... address won't work, you have to use server path.

Comment: I have used it as : unlink('img1.jpg');
but not working

Comment: paste this `http://www.mysite.com/img1.jpg` in your browser and check image is appearing if not YOUR PATH IS WRING

Comment: I am sure I am not making syntax error because I have used it a site before which works fine. Is there any server issue?

Comment: I had the same issue right now. Unlinking or renaming with absolute path e.g. /home/test/someFile.txt and filePermissions of 777 did not work. I just added the line chmod($fileName, 777); before unlink/rename and it did work. I don't know why but even while my file browser told me the permissions are 777 they didn't seem to be 777.

Answer (score 7):

**url not allow in ulink function**

can you please used this

It's better, also safety wise to use an absolute path. But you can get this path dynamically.

E.g. using:

```
getcwd();
```

Depending on where your PHP script is, your variable could look like this:

```
$deleteImage =  getcwd() . 'img1.jpg';

unlink($deleteImage);
```

check this

> ```
> bool unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] )
> ```

and

> *filename*
>       Path to the file.

So it *only* takes a string as filename.

**Make sure the file is reachable with the path from the location you execute the script. This is not a problem with absolute paths, but you might have one with relative paths.**

Comment: Yeah working with getcwd() but I dnt know why not with absolute path. Anyways Thanks Patel .
Reg,
Sunil

Answer (score 3):

Even though unlink() supports URLs ([see here](http://ch2.php.net/unlink)) now, http:// is not supported: [http wrapper information](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)

use a filesystem path to delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use unlink in a linux or unix you should also check the results of [is_writable ( string $filename )](http://php.net/manual/function.is-writable.php)
And if the function returns false, you should check the file permissions with [fileperms ( string $filename )](http://php.net/manual/function.fileperms.php).

File permissions are usual problems on webspaces, e.g. if you upload an file per ftp with a ftp user, and the webserver is running as an different user.

If this is the problem, you have do to a

> chmod o+rwd img1.jpg

or

> chmod 777 img1.jpg

to grand write (and delete) permissions for other Users.

Answer (score 2):

`unlink($fileName);` failed for me.
Then I tried using the `realpath($fileName)` function as `unlink(realpath($fileName));` it worked.

Just posting it, in case if any one finds it useful.

[php unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#84928)

Comment: Fair Warning! realpath() only takes path e.g. "/windows/system32" and not "/windows/system32/temp.jpg". So I used something like this unlink(realpath($tempLoc)."/".$fileName);

Answer (score 1):

use filesystem path,
first define path like this:

```
define("WEB_ROOT",substr(dirname(__FILE__),0,strlen(dirname(__FILE__))-3));
```

and check file is exist or not,if exist then unlink the file.

```
$filename=WEB_ROOT."img1.jpg";
if(file_exists($filename))
{
$img=unlink(WEB_ROOT."img1.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unlink won't work with `unlink('http://www.mysite.com/img1.jpg');`

use instead 
   `unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'img1.jpg');`//takes the current directory
or,

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dir_name/img1.jpg');
```

There may be file permission issue.please check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Give relative path from the folder where images are kept to the file where you are writing script.
If file structure is like:

```
-your php file
-images
  -1.jpg

then 

unlink(images/1.jpg);
```

Or there may be some folder permission issue. Your files are on a server or you are running it on localhost? If it is on a server then give 755 permission to the images folder.

Answer (score 0):

you are using url insted of path, here is how you should do it...
i am assuming your are uploading the picture to public_html. i suggest you to create a folder for pictures.

```
unlink("public_html/img1.jpg");
```